# React / Can't reset current state

Tags: reactjs, calculator

I'm making a calculator app in React. So far every operator work just fine. However when I click "=" button and get the result, and then click another button, the digit won't be added correctly.

I understand there's a lot of redundant code going, but right now I'm focusing the problem that I can't reset digit after I get a result.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        num1: [],
        num2: [],
        operator: null,
        result: null
    };

    currentNumber = (digit) => {

        if(this.state.operator===null) {

            let newNum1 = [...this.state.num1, digit];
            console.log("num1 FIRST", newNum1.join(''));
            this.setState({num1: newNum1.join('')})
            console.log("num1 AFTER", newNum1.join(''));
        }

        if(this.state.num1!==[] && this.state.operator!=null) {
            this.setState({num2: []})
            let newNum2 = [...this.state.num2, digit];
            console.log("num2 FIRST", newNum2.join(''));         
            this.setState({num2: newNum2.join('')})
            console.log("num2 AFTER", newNum2.join(''));
        }
    }

    getResult = () => {
        if(this.state.operator==="+") {
            this.setState({operator: "+"});
            let newNumber = parseInt(this.state.num1) + parseInt(this.state.num2);
            this.setState({result: newNumber})      
        } else if(this.state.operator==="-") {
            this.setState({operator: "-"});
            let newNumber = parseInt(this.state.num1) - parseInt(this.state.num2);
            this.setState({result: newNumber})      
        } else if(this.state.operator==="x") {
            this.setState({operator: "x"});
            let newNumber = parseInt(this.state.num1) * parseInt(this.state.num2);
            this.setState({result: newNumber})      
        } else if(this.state.operator==="÷") {
            this.setState({operator: "÷"});
            let newNumber = (parseInt(this.state.num1)) / (parseInt(this.state.num2));
            this.setState({result: newNumber.toFixed(2)})      
        }
        console.log("Current operator", this.state.operator);
    }

    clearDigit = () => {
        this.setState({num1: [], num2: [], operator: null, result: null});
    }

    displayOperator = (sign) => {
        this.setState({operator: sign});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="calculator_container">
                    <Screen 
                        num1 = {this.state.num1}
                        num2 = {this.state.num2}
                        operator = {this.state.operator}
                        displayNumber = {this.state.result}
                    />

                <Button 
                    onClick = {this.currentNumber}
                    getResult = {this.getResult}
                    clearButtonClick = {this.clearDigit}
                    showOperator = {this.displayOperator}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
class Button extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li><button data-number="1" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>1</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="2" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>2</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="3" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>3</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="x" onClick={event => this.props.showOperator(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>×</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="4" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>4</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="5" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>5</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="6" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>6</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="÷" onClick={event => this.props.showOperator(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>÷</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="7" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>7</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="8" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>8</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="9" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>9</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="+" onClick={event => this.props.showOperator(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>+</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="0" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>0</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="AC" onClick={this.props.clearButtonClick}>AC</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="=" onClick={this.props.getResult}>=</button></li>
                <li><button data-number="-" onClick={event => this.props.showOperator(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>-</button></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

```
class Screen extends React.Component {

    displayAddedNumber = () => {
        this.props.displayNumber();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="display">
                {this.props.num1} {this.props.operator} {this.props.num2}<br />
            <span>{this.props.displayNumber}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i see you have few options:

1. Reset after result (at the end of `getResult()`):

```
this.setState({num1: [], num2: [], operator: null});
```

2. Reset on first digit after result (on top of `displayOperator()` and `currentNumber()`):

```
if(this.state.result){
  this.clearDigit();
}
```

and then switch to using functions in setState instead of object, because you are using old state.

---

also:

1:

```
/*...*/
if(this.state.operator==="+") {
  this.setState({operator: "+"}); // <-- you dont need this, you just aserted it's '+'
  let newNumber = parseInt(this.state.num1) + parseInt(this.state.num2);
  this.setState({result: newNumber})      
}
/*...*/
```

2: Dont make more than one setState in function execution, it's not just bad performance wise but its also very dirty code that you have here
and you should look up into strategy pattern :)

3: you can't compare like that - it won't work because you are comparing object references

```
this.state.num1 !== []
```

you either want to `this.state.num1.length === 0` or `Array.isArray(this.state.num1)` (or both)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and the rest of your correction is very informative. Can't appreciate enough!